# Python app crash after sending command "GPIO.setup( 7, GPIO.OUT)"?

Tags: kernel, python, application-development, gcc

Python app crash after sending command "GPIO.setup( 7, GPIO.OUT)" !!!

Action step:

```
pi@rp:~$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 26 2015, 23:09:09) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup( 7, GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!
exit()
```

Now with sudo :

```
pi@rp:~$ sudo python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 26 2015, 23:09:09) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup( 7, GPIO.OUT)
           . . . python3 crash . . .
pi@rp:~$
```

syslog error report:

```
Jun  1 10:47:40 rp kernel: [ 1160.583861] Program python3 tried to access /dev/mem between 20200000->20201000.
```

Any help will be welcome. Tks.

Comment: Can you add the output of the crash when you run with sudo?

Answer (score 0):

Try unloading the gpio kernel module:

```
sudo rmmod w1-gpio
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included what this command does, in your answer, or at the very least a reference.

Comment: I am editing this post to explain what the command does but I have no idea if it is a suitable fix for the OP's problem

Answer (score -1):

Which kernel are you using? It may have been built with `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`, which disallows access to "/dev/mem".

Note you can still access the GPIO pins via the sysfs interface, but to use something like RPi.

GPIO library, you'll have to ensure that setting is disabled.